# Graphical Datepicker doesn't get displayed correctly

Tags: xcode, swiftui

In this View I want to display the Datepicker on a button click as an overlay.

The Problem is that the time picker is not displayed correctly. Why is that (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThuUD.jpg)?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var date = Date()
    @State var datePickerOn = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("show"){
                datePickerOn = true
            }
            Text("asdf")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .overlay(
            ZStack{
                if datePickerOn{
                    DatePicker("DatePicker", selection: $date)
                        .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
                }
            }
        )
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a non-transparent `background` to the `DatePicker`

Comment: or put it in a sheet